# The chosen colour mode is different from the colour space defined by the document profile

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

Whilst creating a new document in Illustrator, it gives me a warning when I switch the colour mode to RGB:

"The chosen colour mode is different from the colour space defined by the document profile."

[image: Image of Illustrator new document dialogue with warning]

What do I have to do, to get rid of that warning? I do not see any further options in the "new document" dialogue that would allow me to switch colour modes or profiles ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's only a warning that you changed the color mode to one that's different from the original profile you selected to create the new document - i.e. you must have originally chosen a "Print" profile preset, and changed the colour mode to RGB.

It's perfectly OK. There is nothing wrong, and nothing to fix.

All of the "Print" profiles are in CMYK mode by design - since they are intended for print, and print jobs usually have to be CMYK.  If you start with any of the other profiles, these are all RGB.

Answer (score 1):

On the same dialog window, please select a document profile other than "print". Options include: web, devices, basicRGB, etc...